# How to do Lookup with multiple row

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make some kind of Lookup with this kind of table.

[image]

Is it possible or any other way to do this?

Comment: I can't help but notice that 1 and 3 (and "One" and "Three") are actually ODD numbers, not EVEN, and that, likewise, 2 and 4 (and "Two" and "Four") are EVEN numbers and not ODD. So the "Even" and "Odd" labels seem off to me. However, this shouldn't affect formula functionality. It's just a side note to you about my observation.

Comment: Ah sorry i make it in a rush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below formula-

```
=INDEX(B6:C7, SUMPRODUCT(ROW(B2:C3)*(B2:C3=F2))-ROW(B1),SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN(B2:C3)*(B2:C3=F2))-column(A2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do not show your Row numbers or Column letters in your post. But supposing that your search number is in cell F2 and that everything else is arranged relative to that, you can use this rather simple formula in G2:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,{FLATTEN(B2:C3),FLATTEN(B6:C7)},2,FALSE)))`

`FLATTEN` turns a 2D array into a one-column array, working left-to-right and top-to-bottom, which is perfect for a situation like yours.

It is unclear whether you will only be wanting to search that one number and return one result, or whether you will have several numbers in the search column and wish to get their several results. If the latter, the above formula can easily be modified to handle multiple numbers:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(F2:F="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2:F,{FLATTEN(B2:C3),FLATTEN(B6:C7)},2,FALSE))))`

See my comment on your original post as well.

### References

- [FLATTEN function (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761)
- [VLOOKUP function (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [ARRAYFORMULA function (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [IF function (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [IFERROR function (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to use the *`lookup`* *`search_result_array`* parameter, the trick is to work backwards from highest value columns to smallest due to the *`search_key`* not found default behavior of reverting to lower values.

> `=ifna(lookup(E2,$C$2:$C$3,$C$6:$C$7),lookup(E2,$B$2:$B$3,$B$6:$B$7))`

[image]

https://blog.sheetgo.com/google-sheets-formulas/lookup-formula-google-sheets/